# Nested Nginx location with or without trailing slash

Tags: nginx

I am building an application that consists of Laravel at the back end and Nodejs at the front end. To join them I would like to create location in Nginx conf for Laravel via `https://localhost/admin/?` route with or without trailing slash. I have managed to do that with trailing slash but not without.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /certs/localhost.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://nodejs:3000;
      proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }

    # Backend
    location /admin/ {
      alias /var/www/api/public;
      try_files $uri @admin;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri /index.php =404;
          fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
          fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          #fixes timeouts
          fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
          include fastcgi_params;
      }
    }

    location @admin {
        rewrite /admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

   # BrowserSync websocket
    location /browser-sync/socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

}
```

I have tried the following `location ~ /admin/?(.*)$ {` but was unable to get it running as Nginx was looking for a location that doesn't exist. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `location /admin` should match both `/admin` and `/admin/`

Comment: I tried and it does not match route without trailing slash, funny enough it matches 404 from nodejs app available at / location

Comment: Your rewrite statement does not match `/admin` (without a `/`) so `/admin` is never redirected to `/admin/index.php`. You could adjust the regex in the `rewrite` statement or add just add block to handle that specific URI, for example: `location = /admin { rewrite ^ /admin/index.php?/ last; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI `/admin` should result in a redirect anyway, so why not simply add:

```
location = /admin {
    return 301 /admin/;
}
```

Comment: why there is an equal sign before `/admin'?

Comment: It actually does work without an equal sign now, it is just interesting why is it there?

Comment: The equal sign is for "exact" match, so only exact `/admin` URL will be redirect to `/admin/`. If you omit the equal sign, then this will match `/adminfoo`, or `/adminbar` as well, which is undesired. Also, the exact location matching (with `=`) is always faster than prefix location (without it).